# Can I directly upgrade phonegap 1.5.0 to latest version for android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing android apps using phonegap 1.5.0

It seems I am lagging so much for the version of phonegap
as current version is 2.6.0

I went through the upgrading link for android provided by phonegap
here is [a link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android)

But this explains a step by step upgrading.

Can't I directly upgrade phonegap 1.5.0 to latest version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will answer my question

Note: This works fine on windows, I haven't tested this on MAC.

Hope it helps someone.

My colleague tried this.

```
 1. Download latest version of cordova from phonegap site.
 2. Remove build path for cordova_1.5.jar (earlier version) using configure build path.
 3. Remove cordova_1.5.jar (earlier version) from libs folder.
 4. Add cordova_2.6.jar (new version) in libs folder.
 5. Add build path for cordova_1.5.jar (new version) using configure build path.
 6. Remove all files from res/xml folder in your project.
 7. Add config.xml in res/xml folder.
 8. Replace older cordova.js to new one.
 9. Update reference of older cordova.js to new one in all your files.
 10. Add following two lines in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 11. Clean your project and build it.
```

Done your project is updated to latest version of cordova.
Enjoy... :)

Answer (score 1):

I had upgraded from `1.8` to `2.5` directly. What I did was to follow the steps provided [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) to make a sample application with `2.5.` Once it worked, I moved my html, css & js files into the `assets\www\` folder in aprropriate places and updated starting point in the java file. It worked for me in probably 10 mins.

Comment: What about package name? It will be different, if the application is created newly right?

Comment: You can create the new app with the same package name you used on the old one.

Comment: @ranjjose I have tried to create sample app as suggested by in the link. But I am facing some issue while creating app. Is it possible to upgrade app simply by replacing **cordova.jar** and **cordova.js** files in older project?

Comment: @Napster what exactly is the issue that you are facing? Anyway, I don't think just replacing `cordova.jar` & `cordova.js` would work. There has to be appropriate changes in `AndroidManifest.xml` among others.

Comment: @ranjjose When I created project by using existing project, as suggested **[here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)**. Almost all the files like `AndroidManifest.xml, config.xml` were blank. Any idea why this happened? **Note:** I am using Windows 7 and Eclipse IDE.