# Upgrade phonegap from 1.5 to 2.7 for iOS app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have created an app for iPhone in phonegap. 
In starting I used phonegap 1.5 and submitted this app to app store. 
But now I upgrade my app and try to submit to app store. 
Now it is showing error related to **Unique Identifier**.

To resolve it I have to upgrade phonegap from 1.5 to 2.7. 
I checked [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html)

But here upgrade guides are available particular version to version.

Answer (score 0):

Go one by one through the upgrade guides until you get to the version that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but, with android.

My colleague checked all the stages provided [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android).
She reviewed all steps and found that there are minor differences in stages.

So here is [how we upgraded from 1.5 to 2.6 for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230880/can-i-directly-upgrade-phonegap-1-5-0-to-latest-version-for-android).

I suggest you to review the stages for iOS and find out minor differences.
Instead of going stage by stage, check if there are common steps and follow them directly from 1.5 to 2.7