# Upgrading Cordova version from 1.8 to 2.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

am currently using cordova 1.8 version in my application. i want to upgrade it to cordova 2.0 version. i downloaded 2.0 zip file and created new project. Do i need to copy my code to new project or just change the js file of 1.8 version with 2.0 wil work?

Comment: if you have created then you have to major upgrading, other wise you need to use config.xml instead of cordova.xml and plugin.xml.. for more detail please visit:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upgrade to latest version of cordova.

Check this link **[Upgrade cordova 1.5 to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230880/can-i-directly-upgrade-phonegap-1-5-0-to-latest-version-for-android/16437693#16437693)**